# How to re-inject a content script when an inner frame reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension which displays glassdoor ratings next to job listings for my university job board.

Everything runs fine when you first load up the page, however the search function of the site (if you try to search/filter out the job list) reloads an inner frame instead of the entire page. When this happens, my content script does not seem to be re-injecting itself into the new elements that are loaded.

This is the content script that I am sending into the page:

```
var classNames = document.getElementsByClassName("list-item-title");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
    classNames[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}

var i;
var xhr;
var obj;

var employerNames = document.getElementsByClassName("list-item-body");

document.getElementsByClassName("lst-head-l")[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<a href='https://www.glassdoor.com/index.htm'><img src='https://www.glassdoor.com/static/img/api/glassdoor_logo_80.png' title='Ratings Provided by Glassdoor' /></a>");

var apiURL = "https://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?t.p=51863&t.k=kPRnCOceJPO&userip=0.0.0.0&useragent=&format=json&v=1&action=employers&q=";
for (i = 0; i < employerNames.length; i++) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr. open("GET", apiURL + employerNames[i].children[2].children[0].innerHTML, false);
    xhr.send();

    var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (obj.response.totalRecordCount != 0) {
        var child = employerNames[i].children[2].children[0];
        var rawRating = obj.response.employers[0].overallRating;
        var rating = Math.round(rawRating);
        var link = "http://www.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?version=1&action=employer-overview&t.s=w-m&t.a=c&employerId=" + obj.response.employers[0].id;
        var text = "<a href=\"" + link + "\"> <b style=\"color: #7cb228; font-size: 120%;\" title=\" " + rawRating + " \">";

        for (var k = 0; k < rating; k++) {
            text += "&#9733;";
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < (5 - rating); k++) {
            text += "&#9734;";
        }
        text += "</b>";
        child.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', text);
        // employerNames[i].children[2].innerHTML += " <b style=\"color: black\">(" + obj.response.employers[0].overallRating + ") &#9733; </b>";
    }
}
```

I hope the above makes sense, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You should wait for event(s) before searching the DOM. And you should use `"all_frames": true` in your `"content_scripts"`property in your `manifest.json`

Comment: My problem isn't injecting the script innitially when the page loads. When a  user runs a search the page reloads an inner frame to display the results of the search, which my content script does not seem to affect

Comment: Not clear, sorry. If you use `"all_frames": true`, your content script is injected in the inner frame. Please state your problem more precisely.

Comment: If thé inner frame is NOT "reloaded",  but just updated via DOM manipulation after an Ajax query, then you must use an EventListener OR setInterval to "run again" your code when appropriate.